# Update #f="ngForm" variable after editing profile

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I`m using Angular 7 and reactive forms to create Edit Profile page.
I have all my input values filled in from database. If I want to change first name and last name for example, clicking the update button, everything is looking fine, all fields are updated.
The problem is that if I want to update again only the first name, after clicking the update button, last name has intial value. 
So, the problem is that my variable #f="ngForm" is keeping old values (first values) and somehow after update process, #f variable has again first values.

```html
<form [formGroup]="patientEditForm" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="editPatientProfile(f)">
```

```
editPatientProfile(f: NgForm ) {
  this.submitted = true;
  this.isRequesting = true;
  this.errors = '';
  if (f.valid) { 
      this.userService.editPatientProfile(this.patientId,
          this.patient.nin,
          f.value.firstName,
          f.value.lastName,
          this.email,
          f.value.password,
          f.value.city,
          f.value.country,
          f.value.birthdate,
          f.value.phoneNumber)
          .finally(() => this.isRequesting = false)
          .subscribe(
              result => {
                  if (result) {
                      this.router.navigate(['/patient/account']);
                      localStorage.setItem('displayMessage1', "true");
                      window.location.reload();
                  }
              },
              errors => this.errors = errors);
  }
  }
```

```html
 <input type="email" value="{{patient.email}}" disabled class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
```

```
this.patientEditForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      lastName: ['Test', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z]+")]],
      firstName: ['Test', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z]+")]],
      phoneNumber: ['0745119974', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[0-9]+")]],
      birthdate: ['1996-02-10', [Validators.required,this.validateDOB.bind(this)]],
      city: ['Iasi', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z]+")]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(35), this.validatePasswordConfirmation.bind(this)]],
      country: ['Romania', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z]+")]]    
    });
```

Comment: Man did I read `#f=“ngForm”` wrong 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem by setting the new proprieties in subscrive event:

```
 private getPatient() {
    this.userService.getPatient(this.patientId)
    .subscribe((patient: PatientProfile) => {
        this.patient = patient;
        this.patientEditForm.controls['lastName'].setValue(patient.lastName);
        this.patientEditForm.controls['firstName'].setValue(patient.firstName);
        this.patientEditForm.controls['phoneNumber'].setValue(patient.phoneNumber);
        this.patientEditForm.controls['birthdate'].setValue(patient.birthdate);
        this.patientEditForm.controls['city'].setValue(patient.city);
        this.patientEditForm.controls['country'].setValue(patient.country);
    },
    errors => this.errors = errors
    );
```

Comment: Thanks! After a delay you can mark it as accepted and the question will be marked as "answered".